# Callback function running but not the main function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code inside of a route and when I run the debugger, the `theDocu2.save();` function is being run and then the socket emit but I never see the `$set` run which sets the new mongoose values. Any reason for this? Also, in the debugger, values like `bidTime` and `bidAmount` are equal to the previous values that were set the last time this route was run.

```
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.session.passport.user, {
        $set: {
          bidDetails: {
            bidAmount: req.body.bidAmount,
            bidLocation: 'Market Square',
            bidTime: moment().format()
          }
        }
      }, function(err, theDocu2) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        theDocu2.save();
        io.to(theDocu2.email).emit('activeBid', {
          activeBid: req.body.bidAmount,
          bidTime: theDocu2.bidDetails.bidTime
        });
      });
```

Comment: What do you "think" you are doing? `.findByIdAndUpdate()` is meant to "update" the document. So why do you think you need to call `.save()` afterwards? Use one or the other. You are also missing the `{ :"new": true }` option, where otherwise `.findByIdAndUpdate()` returns the "original" document before modification. If anything happens at all here, the net effect is one cancels the other since the `.save()` with "original" data will **overwrite** the modification of `.findByIdAndUpdate()` and the `$set`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari True that the method is async. But there are bigger problems. As I noted, missing the update result of `.save()` is a moot point here.

Comment: Also wondering if `req.session.passport.user` should not be `req.session.passport.user._id`